# Chain Multiple "grep -r" Calls

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find all files (ie. a list of files, not a list of lines in those files) that have pattern X, but don't have pattern Y.  This would be trivial if all my files were in a single directory:

```
grep X * | grep -vl Y
```

... but unfortunately they're not.  If I try to throw in the `-r` option to recurse through my filesystem:

```
grep -r X * | grep -v Y
```

it doesn't work.  It also doesn't work if I throw in the `-l` option (to make it print the file paths instead of the lines within the files):

```
grep -rl X * | grep -v Y
```

However, I feel like there must be a way to combine `grep -r` calls, and I feel like I'm close to a solution, so ... can anyone with better `grep` skills help teach me a pattern for chaining such calls?

Comment: `grep -r X | grep -v Y` would show all lines in all files containing X, and filter out all those lines that also contain Y. Is this what you are looking to do, or, do you want to list the files from `grep -r X` and subtract the files produced by `grep -v Y`?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified (I'll edit my answer).  I'm looking to produce a list of files, not a list of lines.

Comment: Ok so you're looking for `grep -r X | grep -v Y | cut -f1 -d':' | uniq`?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  If you put it in an answer I'll happily accept it (although, purely out of curiosity, I still wonder if there's a way to do it with just `grep` ... but that really isn't important).

Comment: I don't know if I understand your requirement correct, if a file has both `X` and `Y` in different lines, you don't want the file in result right? If it is true, `grep -v` is not the right way to go.

Comment: You understand correctly ... however both answers provided use `-v`, and I've confirmed that @Kenney's solution works, so `-v` seems to be a good way to solve things.

Comment: @machineghost may I post an "answer", to show how this command would fail? It is not a really answer, just for gain better format support? (then it would be removed)

Comment: @machineghost Just to be clear: if what you want is `all files that contain X but not Y (on any line)` you should go with the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification all.  Just goes to show how important it is to understand exactly what one is trying to accomplish before asking others for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would post a new answer although OP has accepted one of them. Because the two answers so far are not working for all cases. `grep -v` is not the right way to go.

first of all, example to prove it: (recursion part is omitted just to make building example easier)

```
==> one_two.txt <==
11111111
222222222

==> one.txt <==
1111111111111

==> two.txt <==
22222222222
```

Let's say, `X` is `1` and `Y` is `2`, that is, we want to find file containing `1` but not containing `2`.

Obviously, only `one.txt` should be in result.

### Answer A: (the accepted one)

```
kent$  grep -r 1 | grep -v 2 | cut -f1 -d':' | uniq  
one.txt
one_two.txt
```

### Answer B:

```
kent$  grep -vl "2" `grep -rl "1" *`       
one_two.txt
one.txt
```

So both gave incorrect result.

### The working solution:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} $0 in a{delete a[$0]}END{for(x in a)print x}' <(grep -rl 1) <(grep -rl 2)
one.txt
```

### explaination

`grep -v pattern` is wrong way, because it will report match if any line in the file not match the pattern.  What we want is, find the two set of files (matching `X` and matching `Y`), do a substract `XSet - YSet`

Comment: Thank you for not settling for an incorrect answer!  However, I have to ask: that working solution is kind of long/fugly.  This seems like a pretty basic operation: 1) find all files with X, 2) find all files without Y, 3) find the union (exactly the sort of thing that the commands like `grep` and Unix pipes were designed to handle).  So again, I really do appreciate your answer, but do I truly need to resort `awk` and all of that other crazy Unix shell stuff I don't understand just to do something so basic?  If so that's totally fine ... it just seems so inelegant.

Comment: @machineghost no you misread my answer. 1) find all files with X 2) find all files **with** Y, 3) Xfiles subtract Yfiles. You can use any other tool even create two temp-result files and do the "subtraction" with editor. I picked awk, because it is (for me) handy to use.

Comment: Gotcha; I guess one man's basic tool is another man's crazy scary Unix wackiness ;-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This doesn't work, because I didn't create my test cases correctly. See below.

Given a setup like:

```
mkdir a
echo "xpat" > a/yes1.txt
echo "xpat noty" > a/yes2.txt
echo "xpat\nypat" > a/no1.txt

mkdir b
echo "something\nelse\nxpat" > b/yes3.txt
echo "ypat\nsomething\nxpat" > b/no2.txt
echo "not that" > b/no3.txt
```

where you want to find the files that contain xpat but not ypat (the three yes?.txt files):

```
grep -vl "ypat" `grep -rl "xpat" *`

a/yes1.txt
a/yes2.txt
b/yes3.txt
```

Here's the correct test case, which fails.

```
mkdir a
echo "xpat" > a/yes1.txt
echo "xpat noty" > a/yes2.txt
echo "xpat
ypat" > a/no1.txt

mkdir b
echo "something
else
xpat" > b/yes3.txt
echo "ypat
something
xpat" > b/no2.txt
echo "not that" > b/no3.txt

grep -vl "ypat" `grep -rl "xpat" *`

a/yes1.txt
a/no1.txt
a/yes2.txt
b/yes3.txt
b/no2.txt
```

I'm still pondering why.

Comment: I accepted Kenney's answer because both answers seemed equally good to me, and he answered first (in the comments).  However, you get bonus points for providing a purely `grep`-based answer, so I wish I could upvote twice :)

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it, if the requirement is "A are all files containing X, B are all files containing Y: show all A not in B", although there might be issues if there are paths with whitespace.

Comment: Except it's wrong, because my test case wasn't right: neither pattern works with patterns on different lines.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
grep -r X | grep -v Y | cut -f1 -d':' | uniq
```

produces all files that *contain a line* containing X and not Y.

This:

```
grep -rl Y > tmp.x
grep -rl X --exclude-from=tmp.x
```

produces all files that contain X and not Y. That is, `X_Files` being all files that contain `X` and `Y_Files` being all files containing Y, it will produce `X_Files - Y_Files`.

---

Example. The setup:

```
mkdir test && cd test
echo foo      > a.txt
echo foo bar >> a.txt
```

The first case:

```
$ grep -r foo | grep -v bar
a.txt:foo
```

The second case:

```
$ grep -rl bar > tmp.x
$ grep -rl foo --exclude-from=tmp.x ; rm tmp.x
```

produces nothing.

Comment: This won't work if `X` and `Y`  in a same file, and located in different lines, will it?

Comment: @Kent That is correct, and this is how it is intended. However it now seems this is not the right interpretation.